# Inserting graph from a software in Latex

Tags: graphs

I made a graph with [Desmos.com](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/2cjpohm2qr).

Which I want to insert in my `LaTeX` code, on the right side of these equations:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)} : \\
\begin{align*}
\overline \rho &= K ~\Big( \sinh ~t ~- ~t\Big)\\
\overline P &= \frac {1}{3} K ~ \Big(\sinh~t -~ 8~ \sinh \frac {1}{2} t  +~ 3t\Big)\\
K &= \frac {1}{4\pi}\\
\end {align*}
\end {document}
```

How can I label the curve on the graph as `P` and `T` and also insert it in my code ?

Comment: Why not to use `pgfplots` for this?

Comment: You can use 2 `minipage`s or 2 `\parbox`es or put them in a `tabular/tabularx` etc for the second question. But you are asking two questions here. Better separate them as two different questions.

Comment: How do you export the graph from Desmos? In a SVG, JPG, whatever image file?

Comment: I was trying to get it in .PNG , though failed . anyway I heard of pgfplots right here, I have never tried it before, can someone show me an example of it using my equations in the code?

Comment: @papiro, closers: The suggested duplicate is about `beamer`, and the accepted answer (the only answer) use `beamer` specific features.

Comment: @TazkeraHaqueTrina: If somehow possible, don't use *.png, *.jpg etc. formats, use *.eps or *.pdf instead, as those are vector formats, scaling well when enlarged/shrinked

Answer (score 2):

Sorry this didn't get an answer earlier. But anyway, here is an example using `pgfplots` and a `minipage` environments.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\begin{document}
\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)}: 

\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\overline \rho &= K \Big( \sinh t - t\Big)\\
\overline P &= \frac {1}{3} K ~ \Big(\sinh t - 8 \sinh \frac {1}{2} t  + 3t\Big)\\
K &= \frac {1}{4\pi}\\
\end {align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(theAxis.west)]
\begin{axis}[
  name=theAxis,
  ymin=-15,ymax=15,
  domain=-8:8,
  samples=50,
  no markers,
  cycle list name=exotic,
  thick,
  width=0.48\textwidth,
  grid, 
  xlabel=$t$,
  ylabel={Something}
%% if you want a legend, uncomment these
%  legend entries={$\overline{\rho}$, $\overline{P}$},
%  legend pos=north west 
]
\addplot {(sinh(x) - x)/(4*pi)} node[left,pos=0.53]{$\overline{\rho}$};
\addplot {(sinh(x) - 8*sinh(x/2) + 3*x)/(3*4*pi)} node[right,pos=0.6]{$\overline{P}$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end {document}
```

If you export the graph from Desmos as e.g. a PNG image, you can do something like this instead, where the image is called `graph.png` and is in the same folder as the `.tex` file. The drawback of this method is that the image will likely require scaling, which will also scale the fonts.

```
\underline {Chandrashekhar EOS (1935)}: 

\noindent\begin{minipage}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
\overline \rho &= K \Big( \sinh t - t\Big)\\
\overline P &= \frac {1}{3} K ~ \Big(\sinh t - 8 \sinh \frac {1}{2} t  + 3t\Big)\\
K &= \frac {1}{4\pi}\\
\end {align*}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{graph}
```